# Free Excel alternative for Mac OS?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I need free alternative of Excel in Mac Os. I know that there is Open Office, but I am not sure if it is even supported anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you need in Excel - some parts are not available in other tools?

Comment: I need viewing and simple editing - nothing fancy, @Mark

Comment: Did you try Numbers?

Comment: No, I installed LibreOffice, but I want to check free MS Office (no time now), @danielAzuelos

Answer (score 11):

By adding a table to Numbers, you can use Apple's replacement instead of a third party's. Numbers is free for anyone with an App Store account (which may require registration and a payment card - but no charge whatsoever).

Numbers is supported and designed to replace Excel for the majority of Mac users.

Answer (score 6):

Excel is available for free from Microsoft as part of an entire suite of products via [Office Online](https://products.office.com/en-US/office-online/documents-spreadsheets-presentations-office-online).

[image]

There's no need to search for a "free" Office alternative when Office is available free as a service.  You will just need to create a Microsoft account to use it.

**The benefits over the alternatives:**

- No software to install (i.e. LibreOffice/Open Office).  All you need is a web browser.
- Native Excel as opposed to "XLS compatible" (which is never really fully compatible)
- Free 5GB OneDrive storage included with your account
- Fairly standardized UI across all devices (macOS, iOS, Windows, Android)

Comment: As I remember there is monthly fee, which is not exactly "free", @Allan?

Comment: You are thinking of their subscription package.  They offer a free online version that doesn't have all the bells and whistles the paid version does.

Comment: So if you want an online version just use GoogleDocs :)

Comment: @bartektartanus - Why when Office is available for free and more prevalent?

Comment: Because prevalent doesn't mean good. Like with any invasive technology, when competition is killed natural selection stops working, and quality fall down.

Comment: @danielAzuelos - Neither does "free" and Libre Office is utter bloatware compared to O365.  How can something be considered invasive when people *choose* to purchase it?  Could it be that with Libre Office, you get exactly what you pay for?

Answer (score 6):

I use [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) which is a really good alternative for MS Office. I've been using it for a couple of years now (on my Ubuntu earlier, now on MacOS).

If you need an online version of Office I recommend GoogleDocs. Full document edit history, collaborative editing, and ease of sharing.