# Is there a way to use math symbols in TextEdit?

Tags: mac, text, text-editor, textedit, latex

For example LaTex, or any other way to show mathematical symbols in TextEdit ?

It's possible to use math symbols in LibreOffice and Microsoft Word, maybe the same is possible in TextEdit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextEdit takes a stream of characters limited only by what fonts are installed. By default you will have lots of maths symbols.

Helps to use *System Settings > Keyboard > Input sources* and enable *Show Input menu in menu bar* to display language icon in menu bar. From the dropdown, click *Show Emoji and Symbols* to show all the characters and fonts available.

Of course, this is just for maths that will look right as a line of characters. If you need something more elaborate, TextEdit is not the right tool. Use LaTex or addins to some word processors.

Comment: The short answer here is TextEdit is a *rich text document editor*.  LaTex which is part of Tex is a markup based framework.  This really doesn't have anything to do with fonts per se.  That said, there are some symbols available as [Unicode characters](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_math_operators.html)  However, these "fonts" don't allow you to edit formulas like LaTeX, Word, or LibreOffice.

Comment: @Allan So there is no way to add math formulas to TextEdit aside of the unicode characters that are already available on any Mac Keyboard (like √ ∫ ∑ π ± ∞ ≤ ≥ etc.) ? If TextEdit doesn't allow it, I would definitely prefer LibreOffice over Word because it's open source (and free)

Comment: @Gilby  So there is no way to add math formulas to TextEdit aside of the unicode characters that are already available on any Mac Keyboard (like √ ∫ ∑ π ± ∞ ≤ ≥ etc.) ? If TextEdit doesn't allow it, I would definitely prefer LibreOffice over Word because it's open source (and free)

Comment: [Microsoft offers a free version of Office](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277948/119271).  Open Source does not make software better.  If it did, Office wouldn’t be such a cash cow for MS

Comment: @wengen Though you can't add complex formulas (like you can with LaTex), you can add more symbols than are on the keyboard.  Many fonts included Maths Symbols, e.g. ∰ But only as single characters.  I wouldn't use TextEdit to compose a research paper, but is sufficient for a few casual one-line formulas.

Answer (score 5):

People who need serious equation capability normally use Pages (Apple’s equivalent of Word or LibreOffice)
instead  of TextEdit.  See here for info:

https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/add-mathematical-equations-tanca5a4fbd9/mac